# Prefab has missing scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using : Unity 2022.2.0b
When I moved the scripts file to another folder, the reference from the prefab was broken.
How can I move scripts files while keeping references?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bD0t.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQYoK.png)

I moved the scripts file to another folder in unity. I also tried with Windows Explorer, but it didn't work either. I also moved the metafile.

Comment: Moving scripts inside Unity should work as well as moving them in explorer as long as you do it while Unity is closed and you also move the metafile. Are they still under Assets?

Comment: Yes, I moved it between folders in Assets/Scripts.
After closing Unity, I moved it with the meta file in Windows Explorer, but the reference from the prefab is broken.

Comment: Try delete the script from the prefab and assign it again and see if it's still has the same behavior, also make sure the script doesn't have any errors and compiles successfully.

Comment: If I remove the script from the prefab and try to assign it again, I get an error message."Can't add script component "script's name" because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match. " 
The script inspector says "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name." 
Opening the script in the IDE and recompiling fixed the reference.But repeating this for every script that should be moved is cumbersome.

Comment: `Opening the script in the IDE and recompiling fixed the reference` .. note that it is not the IDE compiling the scripts but Unity .. try to reimport your scripts via assets right click -> reimport or reimport all

Comment: That worked. But I don't know why the import fails by moving the folder.
Thanks derHugo, Pavlos, Ninja.

Answer (score 0):

solved.
After deleting "ArtifactDB" in the Library directory, I was able to move the scripts to another directory.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the script in the IDE and recompiling fixed the reference as @derHugo said has treat the cause at least, sadly not the syndrome

Deleting Library as user44024 said, solved the cause, i guess. At least still no bugs
user44024